# Auto submit Javascript button action

Tags: javascript, automation

I have a website with a Javascript button, that submits the code entered and refreshes the screen. This is on a open source application and it not my own code.

This button does the job most of the time, but I would like to "hook" into this feature if that is the correct terminology and auto refresh the submit at a specific interval.

```
<button id="dataRefreshButton" type="submit" title="Refresh with latest data." class="button capsule up">
```

I was wondering if there is a way to auto submit this code in some way?

Comment: You want to auto-submit at a specific interval?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

something like `setTimeout()` and `click()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setTimeout(function(){ document.getElementById('dataRefreshButton').click(); }, 5000); // 5 seconds
</script>
```

or `setInterval()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    setInterval(function(){ document.getElementById('dataRefreshButton').click(); }, 5000); // every 5 seconds
</script>
```

Comment: This worked really well and I was surprised on how easy it was! Thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

See http://www.javascript-coder.com/javascript-form/javascript-form-submit.phtml for info on form submission.

As for specific intervals use either

```
setInterval(function() {/*you code*/}, time_interval);
```

or

```
function tick() {
    setTimeout(function() {tick(); /*you code*/}, time_interval);
};
```

with the submission along the lines of:

```
document.forms["myform"].submit();
```